# Auto launching keyboard in Linux when user presses on editable UI components

Tags: linux, qt, keyboard, gtk, dbus

**Problem statement :** The virtual keyboard is required in linux environment which should be launched every time when user presses on editable UI components, like virtual keyboard in iPhone, iPad, Android, etc.

**Solution overview :** As basis for virtual keyboard was taken matchbox-keyboard which is an open-source application and provides rich functionality. The mechanism of auto-toggling was solved by modifying the source of QT and GTK to send Dbus signals on "on_press" signal (when user presses on editable UI comp.) to some daemon which turns virtual keyboard on.

**Issue :** "on_press" Dbus signal is sent when user presses or clicks on UI components i.e. during "on_click" event of QT and GTK. The virtual keyboard is hidden on "focus_out" event of QT and GTK. Keyboard is not switched on during "focus_in" event because some application while launching are emitting "focus_in" event for a moment then emitting "focus_out" event, so virtual keyboard was shows for a short time then hidden which was not accurate. this was solved by generating "on_press" Dbus signal during "on_click" GTK and QT events.

So now here I have another problem.

1. Lets say user pressed on editable box, virtual keyboard appeared, 
   "on_click" (GTK, QT event) -> "on_press" (Dbus signal) -> virtual keyboard is launched
2. Then user presses on Tab button to switch to other editable box.
   "focus_out" (GTK, QT event) -> "hide_keyboard" (Dbus signal) -> virtual keyboard is hidden and is not launched again.

This happens because the second editable box emits "focus_in" event and not "on_click" event.

So please help to find a solution for the case when user switches between editable box with tab button. Or if you have totally other solution please suggest it.

Thanks in advance,
Levon

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of Florence Virtual Keyboard: http://florence.sourceforge.net.
I used at-spi (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistive_Technology_Service_Provider_Interface) to solve the problem. The advantage of at-spi is that it works not only with GTK and Qt but also with java, Firefox and Libre/OpenOffice.

Answer (score 1):

On supported platforms (Embedded Linux, WinCE) Qt emits a special `QEvent` when software input panel should be shown;

```
QEvent::RequestSoftwareInputPanel
```

Description is;

```
A widget wants to open a software input panel (SIP).
```